# Get first row of dataframe in Python Pandas based on criteria without iterating over the whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I want to get the first row of a dataframe where a certain column has negative value:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c'],data=[[2.4,2.3,-1.0]])
index = df.loc[df['c'] < 0].index[0]
```

Now this works but in case I have a dataframe with millions of rows, I don't want to iterate over all of them to get the index. Is there a way to get the index without having to loop over each row? (Would be slow)

Comment: No, OP need efficient solution, so I guess dupe is correct.

Comment: Hmm yes he does mention the df has millions of rows @jezrael

Comment: @yatu - exactly, it is only reason for close, else not. your solution is nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can check which rows in a given column are negative with [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to take the index of the first `True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c'],data=[2.4,2.3,-1.0])
print(df)
    c
0  2.4
1  2.3
2 -1.0

df.c.lt(0).idxmax()
# 2
```

Comment: Doesn't df.c.lt(0) eval each row before idxmax() is applied?

Comment: It does yes, it performs a search over the boolean result @ZacharyRyanSmith

Comment: If df.c.lt(0) evals each row, how is it better than `index = df.loc[df['c'] < 0].index[0]`?

Comment: Because idxmax returns the first true. df['c'] < 0].index[0] looks at the index, no filtering here. @ZacharyRyanSmith

Comment: What result would `idxmax` give if there are no true values (all numbers are positive)? IIUC, it'd give 0 -- so, incorrect