# How to get Index of first Row with none-zero minimum value in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
     U     A         B
0  2000    10       20
1  3000    40        0 
2  2100    20       30
3  2500     0       30 
4  2600    30       40
```

How can I get the index of first row that both A and B have non-zero value and (A+B)/2 is larger than `15` ?

In this example, I would like to get `2` since it is the first row that have non-zero A and B column and avg value of `25` which is more than `15`

Note that this DataFrame is huge, I am looking for the fastest way to the index value.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660088/get-first-row-of-dataframe-in-python-pandas-based-on-criteria) answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets try:

```
 df[(df.A.ne(0)&df.B.ne(0))&((df.A+df.B)/2).gt(15)].first_valid_index()
```

Comment: What if there is `NaN` instead of `0` in one row ? Does it treat `NaN` similar to `0` ?

Comment: Yap, NaN is treated as 0

Answer (score 1):

I find more readable explicit variables, like:

```
AB2 = (df['A']+df['B'])/2 
filter = (df['A'] != 0) & (df['B'] != 0) & (AB2>15)
your_index = df[filter].index[0]
```

**Performance**
For this use case (ridiculous dataset)

```
%%timeit
df[(df.A.ne(0)&df.B.ne(0))&((df.A+df.B)/2).gt(15)].first_valid_index()
**1.21 ms** ± 35.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
AB2 = (df['A']+df['B'])/2 
filter = (df['A'].ne(0)) & (df['B'].ne(0)) & (AB2>15)
df[filter].index[0]
**1.08 ms** ± 28.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df.query("A!=0 and B!=0 and (A+B)/2 > 15").index[0]
**2.71 ms** ± 157 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframe is large, `query` *might* be faster:

```
df.query("A!=0 and B!=0 and (A+B)/2 > 15").index[0]

      2
```