# How to set value of first row of pandas dataframe meeting condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to update the first row of a dataframe that meets a certain condition. Like in this question [Get first row of dataframe in Python Pandas based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660088/get-first-row-of-dataframe-in-python-pandas-based-on-criteria#) but for setting instead of just selecting.

```
df[df['Qty'] > 0].iloc[0] = 5
```

The above line does not seem to do anything.

Comment: show data frame sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `df` below:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  3  1
```

you change the values in the first row where the value in column `b` is equal to 1 by:

```
df.loc[df[df['b'] == 1].index[0]] = 1000
```

Output:

```
      a     b
0     1     2
1  1000  1000
2     3     1
```

If you want to change the value in a specific column(s), you can do that too:

```
df.loc[df[df['b'] == 1].index[0],'a'] = 1000

      a  b
0     1  2
1  1000  1
2     3  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
idx = df[df['Qty'] > 0].index[0]
df.loc[[idx], ['Qty']] = 5
```