# Count and Sum of distinct values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Basically the data set I have has 4 columns as below :-

| UID | Account | Name | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| w1 | A1 | Rohit | 10 |
| w2 | A1 | Rohit | 10 |
| w3 | A2 | Rohit | 100 |
| w4 | B1 | Sakshi | 10 |
| w5 | B2 | Sakshi | 20 |
| w6 | B3 | Sakshi | 30 |

Now for each name I am trying to find using python

1. count of distinct Accounts,
2. sum of amount for those distinct accounts
3. count of UIDs for each name

The output would look like something below

| Name | count of Account | count of UID | Sum of Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rohit | 2 | 3 | 110 |
| Sakshi | 3 | 3 | 60 |

Till now I was able to get the counts using below snippet but couldn't calculate amount.

```
df = df.groupby('Name')['Account','Uid'].nunique()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`DataFrameGroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), we can combine the `nunique` and `sum` operations into one function as shown below:

```
def f(group):
  # Define transformation dictionary
  transform = {}
  # Set Account to be number of unique accounts
  transform['Account'] = group['Account'].nunique()
  # Set Uid to be number of unique UIDs
  transform['Uid'] = group['Uid'].nunique()
  # Find names of the unique accounts
  unique_accounts = group['Account'].unique()
  # For each unique name, get the corresponding amount of the first matching row
  unique_amounts = [group[group['Account'] == u].iloc[0]['Amount'] for u in unique_accounts]
  # Set Amount to the sum of the unique amounts
  transform['Amount'] = sum(unique_amounts)
  # Return a new Series with our transformed data and its labels
  return pd.Series(transform, index=['Account', 'Uid', 'Amount'])


df = df.groupby('Name').apply(f)
```

This results in the following table:

```
        Account  UID  Amount
Name                        
Rohit         2    3     110
Sakshi        3    3      60
```

For more information on applying multiple functions to groupby columns, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47103408/18708485) post. Also, for information on obtaining just the first row of a dataframe that matches a certain criteria, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40660434/18708485) post.

Comment: In the expected output the amount for first row is 110 not 120 @ishawng

Comment: My apologies, I missed that. The answer should be updated to reflect that only unique values are summed.