# Getting the first value of a filtered pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a possibility to get the first value from a filtered dataframe without having to copy and reindexing the whole dataframe?

Lets say I have a dataframe df:

| index | statement | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | True | 123 |
| 2 | True | 456 |
| 3 | True | 789 |
| 4 | False | 147 |
| 5 | False | 258 |
| 6 | True | 369 |

and I want to get the name of the first row with statement that is False.

I would do:

```py
filtered_df = df[df.statement == False]
filtered_df = reset_index(drop=True)
name = filtered_df.loc[0, "name"]
```

but is there an easier/faster solution to this?

Comment: The first value? Row-wise, or column-wise? If it's about the position (first, second, etc), use `.iloc`.

Comment: I want the name of the first row that has statement = True

Comment: `df[df.statement].name.iloc[0]`.

Comment: Your question says "statement that is False", your code shows an example for the case of True, and your comment says "that has statement = True". Which one is it?

Comment: One way would be to write a function, which uses a `for` loop to loop over the rows of the df, and returns the name when it finds a row with statement = False. But there is probably a better way

Comment: what does the "~" exactly do here?

Comment: I mean filtered_df = df[df.statement == False], I edited the question now, sorry.

Comment: for a boolean (True/False) series, `df[~df.statement]` is equivalent to `df[df.statement == False]`. You never need to write `df[df.statement == True]` because `df.statement == True` would evaluate to `df.statement`. The `~` operator simply flips the `True/False` values. See the [pandas docs on boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first row of dataframe in Python Pandas based on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660088/get-first-row-of-dataframe-in-python-pandas-based-on-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

If it is for the name of the first statement that is False, then use

```
df[~df.statement].name.iloc[0]
```

The `~` inverts the selection ("negates"), so only the rows where `df.statement` equals `False` are selected.

Then the `name` column of that selection is selected, then the first item *by position* (not index) is selected using `.iloc[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to make your code neat and more readable is to use pandas method chaining.

```
df.query('statement == False').name.iloc[0]
```

Generally the `.query()` method improves the code readability while performing filtering operations.